# How to create multiple paths for different users

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to programming. I created code that I want to deploy to 5 different users and I want each user to have their own pathed directory back to their folder. Example: users have same path on the network but have their own folders with their names along with the Excel I want to read from. Keep in mind each user will have their own Excel file with different information. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Excel.Application xlAppBows = new Excel.Application();
string pathBows = @"C:\Users\jes.gonzalez\Desktop\BrandtSuite\Bows Template\BOWSLineItemInfo.csv";
Excel.Workbook workBookLabor = xlAppBows.Workbooks.Open(pathBows); 
Excel.Worksheet workSheetBows = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workBookLabor.Worksheets["BOWSLineItemInfo"];
```

Comment: Use a configuration file?

Comment: Never used a config file. Any way you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Please google the technology you're using (I assume you're using a Console application or Windows Forms) and "how to use a config file"  The Internet is already littered with tutorials on that topic.

Comment: Take note of how you've hardcoded a path into `pathBows`.  What about that path could be extracted from it to tell you about the current user, assuming it were running on their machine.  Look into the many ways that .net can tell who the user is, and go from there.  @Amy has pointed you to a fantastic solution, but otherwise this question is way too broad, as there are dozens of ways to accomplish this.

Comment: quick question is it possible to create a var for the hard coded path pathBows to a txt on each user c drive then return the actual path directory?

Comment: Use an app.config file...it will do what your asking about. The classes already exist to read and write them.

Comment: I will give it shot tomorrow. Thanks again!

Comment: It is unclear what “their own pathed directory” is supposed to mean. Do you mean their desktop? Their Documents folder? Investigate [`Environment.SpecialFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.7.1). Or do you mean each user can pick a directory? How they do that depends on what API (WinForm, ASP.NET, WPF, UWP, others) you are using, which you haven't told us.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I essentially just want to be able to path to individuals folder on our network. The way I have it written right now is pointing to my C:it should be pointed to the network. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

question is little bit fogy. 
but, you can have a dictionary for user, path.

this should give you path to my documents folder for Authenticated user

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments, System.Environment.SpecialFolderOption.None)
```